# Buttons "copied" on Drawing on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

So for some reason, when painting Forms to my JPanel, other Elements from the BorderLayout of my JFrame get copied into the Panel. These are my 2 classes:

```
public class Simulation extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentFrame;
    private Map map;

    public Simulation() {
        super("Städte Simulation");
        setBounds(200, 200, 800, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentFrame = new JPanel();
        contentFrame.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        contentFrame.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        javax.swing.JButton jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton("jButton1");
        map = new Map();
        javax.swing.JButton jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton("jButton5");
        contentFrame.add(jButton1, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        contentFrame.add(map, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentFrame.add(jButton5, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        getContentPane().add(contentFrame);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class Map extends JPanel {

    private LinkedList<Town> towns;

    public Map() {
        super();
        this.addMouseListener(new CustomMouseListener());
        towns = new LinkedList<Town>();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (towns.size() > 0)
            for (Town t : towns)
                g.fillRect(t.getX() - 10, t.getY() - 10, 20, 20);
    }

    class CustomMouseListener implements MouseListener {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            towns.add(new Town(e.getX(), e.getY()));
            repaint();
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what happens:
This:
[image]
Turns into this:
[image]

Comment: @MadProgrammer's got your solution in hand. 1+ to his answer, and 1+ to you if you accept it!

Comment: Yeah i see it :) will be able to accept it in 6 Minutes :) ... weird system..

Comment: Side note: You can use a `MouseAdapter` so you don't need all those empty mouse listener methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of a broken paint chain.  Painting in Swing is complex process which is made eaiser by a number of simple methods that you can override.  These methods are chained together in order to provide the functionality used to paint the components.

If you override one of these methods, you are expected to call it's parent implementation.

So, the simple solution would be...

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    if (towns.size() > 0)
        for (Town t : towns)
            g.fillRect(t.getX() - 10, t.getY() - 10, 20, 20);
}
```

However, this is not a good idea.  `paint` is one of the top level methods within the paint chain, it is responsible for call a number of child methods.  In order to maintain functionality and keep things simple, it is recommended that you override `paintComponent` instead

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (towns.size() > 0)
        for (Town t : towns)
            g.fillRect(t.getX() - 10, t.getY() - 10, 20, 20);
}
```

Take the time to read through and understand [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Ps- Swing components are double buffered by default, so there's no need for `contentFrame.setDoubleBuffered(true);`